# What does the code message Jiraiya wrote on Fukasaku's back mean?

Tags: naruto

What did Jiraiya write on Fukasaku's back? How can we decode this?

[image: fukasaku]

> 9,31,8
>   106,7
>   207,15

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answering this question would spoil a key turning point in the anime for you, it makes more sense and would be way more thrilling if you watched the episodes of that arc all the way through.

But if you really, REALLY want to spoil it.
Hover the spoil tag below.... You have been warned!

> The numbers are a code, a code meant only for Naruto to decipher as he is the person closest to him. It's a cipher based off of his book series that he's been working on that gives some critical insight on how Pain works. In his last dying moments he fought like a true shinobi and ensured his enemies demise. The full message reads "The real one's not among them". And to resolve this conflict Naruto must train under the Toads and master sage mode.

Related link:

1. http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Decryption
2. http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:188892

Answer (score 5):

The code left by Jiraya was meant to be a hint from one of his books and the very first letters of their page numbers.

The number "9" isn't actually a number.  It's a Katakana letter タ from the Japanese language that reads as "ta", by which he meant his book's name 'Make Out **Ta**ctics'.

By "31,8", Jiraya meant the 8th word on page 31.
By "106,7", he meant the 7th word on page 106.
By "207,15", he meant the 15th word on page 207.
And all these words read: "THE - REAL- ONE'S -NOT -AMONG-THEM".

Comment: Hi. This site requires or highly encourages sources and references for answers. While I might know from which chapter or volume this is (and I know most of what is in the answer is true), not all people do, so an edit may be necessary. Include necessary volumes and chapters, and try to find out why your translation of the coded message is wrong.